# convert and resize vector

Tags: vector, type-conversion, vhdl

I have following code (simplified):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is

    signal slv16 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
    signal slv5  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);      

begin

    slv16 <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(slv5), slv16'length));

end architecture;
```

I get an error message that 'resize' can not be matched to a subprogram. Why?

Comment: I don't know. I see nothing wrong with it. I've tried it on 3 different simulators and they think it's OK, too: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/pRr. What simulator are you using?

Comment: Show the entire error message(s) and any warnings which will also indicate the tool. `resize [unsigned, natural return unsigned] is declared in package numeric_std.

Comment: No error with GHDL (`ghdl -a --std=08 --ieee=standard`) or Mentor Graphics Modelsim (`vcom -2008`).

Comment: For -1993, etc. as well. unsigned and std_logic_vector are closely related for purposes of type conversion. They have the same element base type.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the problem. I used this two libraies:

```
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
```

while both have the same implemenation for **unsigned** as follows:

```
type UNSIGNED is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
```

after deleting the synopsis library the error message is gone. Although I understand the problem here the error message above gave me a wrong direction to look at.

Thanks!

Comment: The code in your question does not `USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;`; you might want to edit it to show this. The error message is what you would expect because in VHDL, when you have multiple definitions for the same subprogram, all will be ignored, in order to alert you to the conflict.

Comment: ok - this explains why I got such error message when all libs are ignored in such case.